# Can I replace the ceramic capacitor with tantalum?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction, compensation, tantalum

In the following topology, a 2200nF multilayer ceramic capacitor (SR305E225MAR) is used in the compensation network. Can I replace it with a tantalum capacitor with equivalent voltage and capacitance? If so, how should I consider the polarity? The ceramic capacitors are non-polar while the tantalum caps are polar.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Tantalum capacitors have some undesirable properties like going up in flames. I’d suggest you use a ceramic capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the data sheet at https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6562a.pdf you can see the block diagram:
[image]

C3 (in-series with a 22kohm resistor) forms part of a compensation network for the converter - I expect that under normal operating conditions the voltage across this cap can be positive or negative at times, and is thus tantalum parts would be unsuitable. That being said if you must avoid ceramic I’d bet a polyester film capacitor would work as well.